# Moving files with npm build

Tags: reactjs, npm-build

I have a project I created with create react app. What I would like to achieve is when I run `npm run build` I want to move the files into the root directory without creating another folder. The reason for this is because I have my GIT repo setup so when I run a git push, the files go to production on my server.

I've tried the following:

```
// package.json
  "scripts": {
    "build": "BUILD_PATH='./root' react-scripts build",
    // ...
  },
```

but this just creates a folder called root with the build contents. I'm trying to move just the files created by the build without creating a folder.

Thanks!